# Grammar based question

Tags: pronouns

Example:
1) One of the most important technical requirements for the aerospace applications is the fatigue properties of the aerospace materials because they reflect on the lifetime of aircrafts.

In this sentence, what does "they" refer to (fatigue properties or aerospace materials)? Solely based on the context of grammar.

Comment: One (of something) is the fatigue properties (of something) because they (do something). Personally, I'd go with *fatigue properties*, but the sentence is not constructed with absolute clarity.

Comment: “fatigue properties”-  reduce the sentence to its minimum: *One (requirement) is the properties because they reflect...*

Comment: The 'extract' is ungrammatical and illogical (how can fatigue properties be a technical requirement?) It doesn't make sense to ask people to interpret such material.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually very difficult to analyse any sentence purely on the basis of grammar, without using context or prior knowledge at all. Language generally requires a great deal of **inference** on the part of the listener or reader - guessing, in other words.  (This is true of all perception, actually).

Purely using grammar, it's impossible to say.  Using prior knowledge, and the available context information, my *guess* would be that "they" refers to "*the fatigue properties of the materials*".  This would actually be partly dependent on the choice of material, as well as other aspects like how old it is etc.